# Spotfire Map Charts - Multislelect Location

Tags: dictionary, charts, spotfire

I'm pretty new to Spotfire Map Charts.

I am looking to build a dashboard which would be maintained in SharePoint Lists. We have a column - 'Location' which would have the region (countries) that are affected by a particular row. It is a multiselect data type.

From what i have tried on the map charts so far, it seems i would have to give in the Longitude and Latitude information. However, the data i have looks more in the following fashion:

Row 1 : United States; Canada
Row 2 : Mexico; Chile; China
Row 3 : Germany
Row 4 : Brazil; Canada

For my purpose, i would want to show the locations to show up on the Map charts and would read the data as follows:

United States: 1
Canada : 2
Mexico : 1
Chile : 1
China : 1
Brazil : 1

Can someone please guide me how i can go about doing that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your first obstacle getting your Countries to render on your spotfire map?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking of couple of options to work around it. Since, the number of countries is going to be limited. Maybe have a Boolean column (like a checklist) for each country and have a value Yes/True if it is applicable. I think this makes the issue bit simpler, but i have not yet been able to figure out how to have it appear on the maps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to use the geocode my data but was still having issues due to my data being a multi-select. To simplify things for me, i made changes to the source (Made a different table, which would clean the data and have a single country in each column, this is then imported into Spotfire) and was able to make it work.

This is a workaround, not a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You posted a comment as a solution and accepted it. Did you realize that?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is georectify your data by your Country. What this does is match your Countries with a coordinate from a database or reference table. You will need a column that has ONE country for each row. You can also have Regions, Cities, Zip Codes, etc.  The steps are lengthy to type, but Spotfire has a great short video on this. For your situation, you can start the video at the 2:18 mark.

http://spotfire.tibco.com/qrt/5G93S/5G93S.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will go over the tutorial and try the steps. Will reach out if i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Sounds good. I suggest making sure you don't have any leading or trailing spaces in your columns.

Comment: @Dfangs did you get this implemented?

Comment: Apologies for delay in my response. I was able to geocode my data, thanks for the reference! However it did not solve my issue which was with multiselect location to be read by Spotfire.

Comment: Well geocoding it was the first problem. Multi select was a problem that would come AFTER you correctly render your data. You didn't need to split the data. That was kind of pointless.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not following you. What is the pointless part ?